# Blocking a DatePicker change from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datepicker

I have defined a simple DatePicker:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SomeDate}"/>
```

And I'd like to prevent the user from clearing the value under some conditions.

Here's what I got so far:

```cs
public DateTime? SomeDate
{
    get { return someDate; }
    set
    {
        if (someDate != value)
        {
            if (value == null && someCondition)
                TellTheUserHeCannotClearTheField();
            else
                someDate = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(() => SomeDate);
        }
    }
}
```

While this keeps the underlying field from being updated, the DatePicker still displays an empty value (i.e. *"<Enter text here>"*), and tries to update the property to null again each time the user tabs through it.

How can I force the DatePicker to display the current, unchanged value?

---

Based on Doc's comments answer, let me generalize this a bit.

When using the dropdown, it is possible to reject date changes in this way (if I wanted to restrict the range, for example).

But if you use the keyboard, whatever you typed remains in there and the DatePicker will try to commit it every time it loses focus.

Comment: I'm trying to understand... are you asking how to disable property updates after `TellTheUserHeCannotClearTheField()` has been called?

Comment: @Doc I'm trying to keep the user from clearing the value (i.e. setting `someDate` to null) if `someCondition` is true. `TellTheUserHeCannotClearTheField()` is just a `MessageBox.Show(some info)`.

Comment: Ok -- so it's almost like you want the DatePicker to consider the datatype not nullable after your condition is met.  Would [IDataErrorInfo](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) work?

Comment: @Doc forget about the null. Assume I don't want the date to be set to July 17 because it's my birthday and that makes me sad. When the user enters July 17, I want the value to revert to whatever was in there before.

Comment: Hmm.  Is the getter getting called after the setter?  Does a second `NotifyPropertyChanged` call update the DatePicker contents? (Preferably in a new call stack.)

Comment: @Doc yes, DateOfDeath is being read again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reasonably good fix.

The problem is that the `SelectedDate` property is updated correctly, but the `Text` property (which is what is displayed) is now out of sync.

Therefore, I wrote a helper to keep it in sync:

```
public class SelectedDateSyncBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SyncTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("SyncText", typeof(bool), 
            typeof(SelectedDateSyncBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, 
                                                  HandleSyncTextChanged));

    static void HandleSyncTextChanged(DependencyObject d, 
                                      DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            ((DatePicker)d).LostFocus += SyncText;
        else
            ((DatePicker)d).LostFocus -= SyncText;
    }

    static void SyncText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = (DatePicker)sender;
        if (picker.SelectedDate != null)
            picker.Text = picker.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }

    public static void SetSyncText(DatePicker element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(SyncTextProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetSyncText(DatePicker element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(SyncTextProperty);
    }
}
```

Now all I have to do is:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SomeDate}" 
            myns:SelectedDateSyncBehavior.SyncText="True"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce it.

I set up the property `TestDate` like so:

```
private DateTime? _testDate = DateTime.Now;

public DateTime? TestDate {
  get { return _testDate; }
  set {
    if (value < DateTime.Now)
      System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("BAD!");
    else
      _testDate = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("TestDate");
  }
}
```

And a DatePicker like so:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding TestDate}" />
```

And this is my behavior:

- *Selecting "bad" date (jan 16th)*:

[image]

- *Bad message*:

[image]

- *Value unchanged from original*:

[image]

- *Selected good date (works)*:

[image]

This example is the same as what you're trying to do, right? (My MVVM implementation is a little different.)

Comment: Maybe `null` **is** special. Plus, I'm using the keyboard, not the selector. I'll do some more testing and update my question. Thanks!

Comment: it work as expected with the dropdown, but **not** with the keybord. Type 1/21/2013 and you will see that it remains there after showing the error. I'll add this to the question.

Comment: Bizarre.  I see that the getter is getting called as expected.  I've called the PropertyChanged from a button click as well and it still doesn't update the SelectedValue.  I'll tinker with it.

Answer (score -1):

the standard WPF `DatePicker` does not have something like `IsReadOnly`. The only way to prevent user input is to disable it:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SomeDate}" IsEnabled="{Binding AllowEditSomeDate}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public bool AllowEditSomeDate {get;set;} //Do not forget INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Comment: Please read the question. I don't want to disable input; I want to prevent the entering of a null value if `someCondition` is true.